# Drag function doesn't apply to first selection where the click is initiated

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The following code is meant to highlight counties via mousemove and mouseclick. The code works mostly correct, the only problem I'm having trouble solving is when I click and move the mouse, the first selection is not highlighted and is being skipped (I can go back and click it to select it but it's annoying it doesn't select it the from the start).

Thanks for the help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Heartland Remapping Tool</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/faviconpng.png"/>
<style>
svg{
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
}
.counties, .unhovered {
  fill: white;
  stroke: #7887AB;
  stroke-width: .5px;
}
.counties .hovered, .counties :hover {
  fill: #061539;
  stroke-width: 0px;
}
.selected {
  fill: #061539;
}
.deselected {
  fill: white;
}
.deselected :hover {
  fill: white;
}
.county-borders {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #F0F8FF;
  stroke-width: .2px;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.state-borders {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #162955;
  opacity: .8;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  pointer-events: none;
}
</style>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.min.js"></script>
<script>
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var path = d3.geoPath();
var clickDown = true;
var numSelectedCounties = 0;
var selectedCounties = {};

d3.json("https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json", function(error, us) {
  if (error) throw error;
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "counties")
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", path);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "state-borders")
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.nation).features)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", path);
  svg.append("path")
      .attr("class", "state-borders")
      .attr("d", path(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.nation, function(a, b) { return a !== b; })));
  svg.append("path")
      .attr("class", "state-borders")
      .attr("d", path(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; })));
  svg.append("path")
      .attr("class", "county-borders")
      .attr("d", path(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.counties, function(a, b) { return a !== b; })));

//Clicking stuff below.

  let hoverEnabled = false;

  svg.selectAll('.counties path')
  .on('mousedown', x => hoverEnabled = true)
  .on('mouseup', x => hoverEnabled = false)
  .on('mouseover', function() {
    if (hoverEnabled) {
      if (!d3.select(this).classed('hovered')) {
        d3.select(this).classed('hovered', true);
        numSelectedCounties++;
      }
    }
  })
  .on('click', function() {
      if (d3.select(this).classed('hovered')) {
        d3.select(this).classed('hovered', false);
        numSelectedCounties--;
      }
      else {
        d3.select(this).classed('hovered', true);
        numSelectedCounties++;
      }
  })
  });
</script>
```

Comment: click and mousemove is called drag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `mousedown` you set a flag to see if you are dragging; then `mouseover` sets the color.  Well the `mouseover` event for the county you just mouse-downed in already occurred, so it's not going to set the color.

I'd simplify all your event handling to:

```
let hoverEnabled = false;
svg.selectAll('.counties path')
  .on('mousedown', function(){
    var self = d3.select(this);
    hoverEnabled = !self.classed('hovered');
    self.classed('hovered', hoverEnabled);
  })
  .on('mouseup', function(){ hoverEnabled = false; })
  .on('mouseover', function() {
    if (hoverEnabled){
      d3.select(this).classed('hovered', true);
    }
  });
```

Also, I wouldn't bother keeping a count of "selected counties".  It's cleaner to just figure it out when you need it with:

```
d3.selectAll('.hovered').size();
```

Running code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Heartland Remapping Tool</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/faviconpng.png"/>
<style>
svg{
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
}
.counties, .unhovered {
  fill: white;
  stroke: #7887AB;
  stroke-width: .5px;
}
.counties .hovered, .counties :hover {
  fill: #061539;
  stroke-width: 0px;
}
.selected {
  fill: #061539;
}
.deselected {
  fill: white;
}
.deselected :hover {
  fill: white;
}
.county-borders {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #F0F8FF;
  stroke-width: .2px;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.state-borders {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #162955;
  opacity: .8;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  pointer-events: none;
}
</style>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.min.js"></script>
<script>
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var path = d3.geoPath();
var clickDown = true;
var numSelectedCounties = 0;
var selectedCounties = {};

d3.json("https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json", function(error, us) {
  if (error) throw error;
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "counties")
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", path);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "state-borders")
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.nation).features)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", path);
  svg.append("path")
      .attr("class", "state-borders")
      .attr("d", path(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.nation, function(a, b) { return a !== b; })));
  svg.append("path")
      .attr("class", "state-borders")
      .attr("d", path(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; })));
  svg.append("path")
      .attr("class", "county-borders")
      .attr("d", path(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.counties, function(a, b) { return a !== b; })));

  let hoverEnabled = false;
  svg.selectAll('.counties path')
  .on('mousedown', function(){
    var self = d3.select(this);
    hoverEnabled = !self.classed('hovered');
    self.classed('hovered', hoverEnabled);
  })
  .on('mouseup', function(){ hoverEnabled = false; })
  .on('mouseover', function() {
    if (hoverEnabled){
      d3.select(this).classed('hovered', true);
    }
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help, Mark. This worked great.